# What is the implication of using request.user over self.request.user

Tags: python, django

I want to know the major difference between `self.request.user` (when using generic view **View**) and `request.user` (when using a user defined view), at times when I use django's generic **View** (`django.views.generic import View`) which has access to the django **User** model, I'd interact with the authenticated user as `request.user` and `self.request.user` without having any problem.

For instance, in a django **views.py**:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class GetUserView(View):
    def get (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_qs = User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username)
        #Do some other stuffs here


class AnotherGetUserView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_qs = User.objects.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
        #Do some other stuffs here
```

I realize that the two queryset works fine but I can't still figure out the best to use.

Comment: There's no difference I'm aware of.

Comment: both are the same, no difference at all

Comment: I thought as much, thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no difference. Before triggering the `get` method, it will run the `setup()` method which will set `self.request = request`. It however does not make much sense to do `User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username)`: you already have the user object: that is `request.user`, so here you will only make extra database requests. `user_qs` is simply a queryset with *one* element: `request.user`.

Comment: see this https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py#L29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Before triggering the `get` method, it will run the [**`.setup(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup) which will set `self.request = request` as well as `self.args` and `self.kwargs` to the positional and named URL parameters respectively. Unless you override this, `self.request` will thus always refer to the same object as `request`, and the documentation explicitly says that you should not override the `.setup(…)` method without making a call to the super method which will thus set `self.request`.

It however does not make much sense to do `User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username)`: you already have the user object: that is `request.user`, so here you will only make extra database requests. `user_qs` is simply a queryset with *one* element: `request.user`. You can thus for example use `request.user.email` to obtain the email address of the logged in user.

You might want to use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to ensure that the view can only be called if the user has been logged in, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class GetUserView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    
    def get (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # …
```